# Inconsistent setfacl behaviour between Windows and Linux with bind mounts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There is an inconsistent behavior of `setfacl` between Windows (and possibly MacOS) and Linux. Seems that `setfacl` cannot be used with folders in a bind-mount on Linux, only on Windows (and possibly MacOS).

You can try it yourself with this [minimal repository](https://github.com/gremo/docker-setfacl-behaviour).

Given:

- `folder-volume`: a Docker **volume**
- `folder-bind`: a regular **folder** inside a Docker bind-mount

#### The problem

Running `setfacl` on `folder-volume`:

> `setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX /workspace/folder-volume`

- ✅ Windows works fine
- ✅ Linux works fine

Running `setfacl` command on `folder-bind`:

> `setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwX -m u:"$(whoami)":rwX /workspace/folder-bind`

- ✅ Windows works fine
- ❌ Linux throws the error *Not supported*

[image: setfacl]

I'm seeing this after switching to Linux for work. Anyone has a solution or as noted the same?

Comment: How is this programming related? It looks like it belongs on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Linux does not support setting ACLs on bind mounts, while Windows and MacOS do.

On Linux, when you mount a directory into a container using -v host_dir:container_dir (bind mount), the host directory ACLs are not preserved.

The bind mount ignores the ACLs on the host.

So when you try to run setfacl on the bind mounted directory inside the container, it fails with "not supported" error on Linux.

Whereas on Windows and MacOS, ACLs are preserved in bind mounts.

So setfacl works as expected on a bind mounted directory inside a Docker container.

The workaround on Linux is to use a Docker volume instead of a bind mount, as you have demonstrated.

Docker volumes support ACLs on Linux, so setfacl will work as expected there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,ACLs are used to set permissions beyond the traditional Unix permissions and on Linux the `setfacl` may not work as expected on bind-mounted folders because the underlying file system may not support ACLs,so this is likely why you are getting the `Not supported` error, but Windows or MacOS have their own implementations of ACLs, which may work differently and support ACLs on bind-mounted folders.

if ACLs are crucial for your use case and you need consistent behavior across different operating systems, so just use different methods, such as network file system (NFS) or a distributed file system that supports ACLs consistently across platforms.

Comment: Well, I see, such pita. I think that Docker behaviour should be consistent between OS.

Comment: @gremo since Docker runs on top of the host operating system, it is limited by the underlying file system and its capabilities.you may need to explore alternative solutions such as using a network file system (NFS) or a distributed file system that supports ACLs consistently across platforms because it will ensure that your ACL requirements are met regardless of the underlying operating system!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, setfacl does not work on bind mounts. But you can use this method to copy permissions from the original folder to the bind mount:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Getting permissions of original folder
perms=$(stat -c "%A" /workspace/folder-bind)

# Copying permissions to bind mount
chmod -R $perms /workspace/folder-bind
```

This will simply copies all the permissions from the original folder to the bind mount, and then sets the default permissions for any new files created in the bind mount. This way, any changes to permissions in the original folder will also be reflected in the bind mount.

Note: This is only the workaround and may not work for all scenarios.

using filesystem permissions instead of extended ACLs for setting umask for the folder-bind to the desired permission for newly created folders

```
mkdir -m 755 folder-bind
```

command to have all new folders 755 permissions, the rules will only work for those newly created folders. the ones that you already made won't be affected

Comment: Thanks, the problem I'm facing is to make new folders inside the folder-bind to inherit parent permission i.e. the user permissions

Comment: @gremo Unfortunately, there is no way to directly inherit the parent permissions for newly created folders inside a bind mount. This is because bind mounts do not have their own file system, so any newly created folders are actually created in the original folder, not in the bind mount.

To work around this issue, you can use the same method mentioned above to copy the permissions from the parent folder to the newly created folder. This will ensure that the new folder has the same permissions as the parent.

Comment: Another method is to use filesystem permissions instead of extended acls. This means setting the umask for the folder-bind to the desired permission for newly created folders. so, if you want all new folders to have 755 permissions, you command `mkdir -m 755 folder-bind` 

but know that this will only apply to newly created folders and will not retroactively change the permissions of existing folders.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some key points to consider:

1. File Systems:

On Linux, the standard file system is typically an ext4 or similar file system, which uses traditional `POSIX file permissions (i.e., owner, group, and others)` to control access.
On Windows, the file system is typically `NTFS`, which uses Access Control Lists (ACLs) to manage permissions. Windows ACLs are more fine-grained and flexible compared to `POSIX` permissions.

2. Bind Mounts:

When you create a bind mount between a Windows system and a Linux system, the two systems must negotiate how permissions and `ACLs` are applied, which can lead to inconsistencies.

3. `setfacl` Command:

The `setfacl` command on Linux is used to manage `POSIX ACLs`.
On Windows, there's no direct equivalent to the `setfacl` command. Windows uses its own security mechanisms, which may not be directly compatible with POSIX ACLs.

3. Ownership and Permissions:

Ownership and permissions of files on Windows and Linux may not directly translate when using bind mounts. The way permissions are interpreted can differ.